# react-router-dom version 6 nested routes props not passing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am unable to get the props from the nested routes, `Products` route has nested route which should print `pc` but I only get ssd,

Is this because I am using same component in the nested route ? or I am doing something wrong.

App.js

```js
<BrowserRouter>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="products" element={<Products name="ssd"/>}>
            <Route path=":id" element={<Products ye="pc" />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<Err />}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Products.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function Products(props) {
    const {id} = useParams(); 
    console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
        <p>This product : {props.name} is in stock</p>
        <p>The id from the params is : {id}</p>
        <p>ye is : {props.ye}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Products
```

Here is the screenshot of the console which show that only `ssd` is passed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Products` is missing rendering an `Outlet` for nested `Route`s to be rendered into.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function Products(props) {
  const { id } = useParams(); 
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This product : {props.name} is in stock</p>
      <p>The id from the params is : {id}</p>
      <p>ye is : {props.ye}</p>
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render out here
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or alternatively if you don't want to nest `Products` components within other `Products` components, render the `Outlet` as the layout component and create an index route for the "ssd" route. The `Route` component renders an `Outlet` by default if no `element` prop is specified.

```
<Route path="/products">
  <Route index element={<Products name="ssd" />} />   // <-- "/products"
  <Route path=":id" element={<Products ye="pc" />} /> // <-- "/products/1234"
</Route>
```